# Find out code coverage of a running Android application

Tags: android, code-coverage

I am trying to figure out a way to do this. I have heard about EMMA Code Coverage Tool and some others. But, I don't think that's what I want.

Basically what I want to do is, I have an Android app installed in my phone and I use the app normally. I want to find out how much %age of the application code have I covered. Consider that I just have the apk of the app and nothing else. So, I don't have access to the code or anything.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe using adb or some third party apps installed in the android device?

Comment: You're trying to create unit tests for an application when you don't have the source code ? May I ask why ?

Comment: I just want to find out how much percentage of the application have I browsed / used .....that's it :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you on this one, and I personally don't think it is possible. Good luck.